# How to fix javax.net.ssl.SSLException

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to a database using MySQL Workbench in Java. The connection should be between two computers. The host without the database has this string to establish connection : "jdbc:mysql://192.168.43.26:3306/DATABASEE?user=admin&password=toor"
192.168.43.26 is the actual IP of the server; and DATABASEE the name of the database.

```
public static int CheckLogin(String Username, String Psw) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Create a variable for the connection string.
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.43.26:3306/DATABASEE?user=admin&password=toor";

        try {Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet sr = stmt.executeQuery("select * from Users;");
            while(sr.next()) {
                String S = sr.getString("Username");
                String S2 = sr.getString("Psw");
                if(S.equals(Username) && S2.contentEquals(Psw)) {
                    con.close();
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            con.close();
        }
        // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

After the execution of the following code Eclipse gives me the following errors:

```
    Fri Oct 18 18:01:40 CEST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
    Fri Oct 18 18:01:41 CEST 2019 WARN: Caught while disconnecting...

    EXCEPTION STACK TRACE:



    ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

    javax.net.ssl.SSLException
    MESSAGE: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify

    STACKTRACE:

        javax.net.ssl.SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:129)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:255)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:645)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:624)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.quit(MysqlIO.java:2246)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:4236)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionImpl.java:1462)
            at Ciao.OpenSQL.CheckLogin(OpenSQL.java:132)
            at Ciao.MasterStart.actionPerformed(MasterStart.java:160)
            at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
            at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
            at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
            at 

java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

Comment: OT but you should use a WHERE clause specifying both columns and just count the matches, not select the whole table and search the whole yourself. This doesn't scale. Let the database do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the same error even though I'm using where clause instead fetching whole table.

Adding useSSL=false to my database url solved the issue:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnetion("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/abc?useSSL=false","username","password");
```